# Codeigniter - Not able to upload files from multiple file inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, ajaxform

I have a multi-steps form which has many input fields including multiple file inputs and some of them are dynamically generated with the JavaScript.In one section of the form, users can upload multiple files. I am able to insert the form data into the database but not able to upload those multiple documents files which users upload.I am using AJAX to upload form data and files. This is my controller code,

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Employee extends MY_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'employees';
        $this->view('employees/view_employee_view', $data);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $req = $this->input->post();

            // Some other code here

            // First upload the profile picture
            if (!empty($_FILES['emp_photo']) AND $_FILES["emp_photo"]["error"] == 0) {

                // Upload employee photo
                $emp_photo_data = $this->upload_file(EMP_PHOTOS_FOLDER, 'emp_photo');

                if (array_key_exists('error', $emp_photo_data)) {
                    $this->response(['success'=>false, 'msg' => '<b>File upload failed!Try again</b>', 'data'=> ''], 500);
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $employee['emp_photo'] = $emp_photo_data['file_name'];
                }
            }
            
            $this->db->trans_start();

            $emp_id = $this->Employee_model->save($employee);

            // Save edu details of employee
            $this->add_edu_details($emp_id);

            // Upload employee documents
            $doc_details = $this->upload_emp_docs($emp_id); //<-- Here is the problem
            
            if (is_string($doc_details)) {
                // it's an error
                $this->response(['success' => false, 'msg' => '<b>Employee documents upload failed!</b>', 'data' => $doc_details]);
                $this->db->trans_rollback(); 
                exit();
            }
            else{
                if ($doc_details === FALSE) {
                    // Error occured - rollback
                    $this->response(['success' => false, 'msg' => '<b>Employee documents upload failed!</b>', 'data' => '']);
                    $this->db->trans_rollback();
                    exit();
                }
            }

    }


    private function upload_emp_docs($emp_id)
    {
        $counts = $this->input->post('emp_docs_count');

        $req = $this->input->post();
        
        $data = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $counts; $i++) { 
            
            if (!empty($_FILES['emp_doc_' . $i])) {
                $res = $this->upload_file(EMP_DOCS_FOLDER, 'emp_doc_' . $i, 'pdf');
                $done = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["emp_doc_" . $i]["tmp_name"], EMP_PHOTOS_FOLDER . md5(time()) . '.jpg');
                if (array_key_exists('error', $res)) {
                    return $res['error']; // return error string
                }
                else {
                    $data[$i] = ["emp_id" => $emp_id, 'file_name' => $res["file_name"], 'doc_type'=> $req["emp_doc_type_{$i}"] ];
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $done = $this->Emp_doc_model->save($data);
            return !empty($done) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code in **MY_Controller.php** which actually do the uploading task

```
public function upload_file($dir, $input, $allowed_types = 'jpeg|jpg|png')
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = $dir;
        $config['allowed_types'] = !empty($allowed_types) ? $allowed_types : 'jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = 0;
        $config['max_width']     = 0;
        $config['max_height']    = 0;
        $config['file_name']     = md5(time() . rand(1, 1000));

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($input)) {
            return array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            // If it is image then resize it to reduce the image file size
            if ($data['is_image']) {
                $this->resize_image($data['full_path']);
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }
```

In one section a user can select a profile picture and I am able to upload that file using the above code but I am not able to find why it is not working when I try to upload multiple files.

This is the HTML code for that section

```
<div class="col upload-area">
<div class="input-group">
   <a class="btn bg-grey btn-block" id="add-file-group">ADD FILE</a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="emp_docs_count" name="emp_docs_count" value="1">
<div class="row clearfix file-upload-group">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-line">
            <input name="emp_doc_1" type="file" class="form-control">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-line">
            <select name="emp_doc_type_1" id="emp_doc_type_1" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose one of the following...">
               <option value="<?= OFFER_LETTER ?>"><?= OFFER_LETTER ?></option>
               <option value="<?= APPOINT_LETTER ?>"><?= APPOINT_LETTER ?></option>
               <option value="<?= CONF_LETTER ?>"><?= CONF_LETTER ?></option>
               <option value="<?= APP_LETTER_1 ?>"><?= APP_LETTER_1 ?></option>
               <option value="<?= APP_LETTER_2 ?>"><?= APP_LETTER_2 ?></option>
               <option value="<?= REL_LETTER ?>"><?= REL_LETTER ?></option>
               <option value="<?= EXP_TER_LETTER ?>"><?= EXP_TER_LETTER ?></option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i></button> -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  waves-effect remove-me"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the JS code to generate input tags dyanmically

```
$("#add-file-group").click(function() {
    // Dynamically generate the id for upload-group elements
    const count = $(".upload-area").find(".file-upload-group").length + 1;

    const newID = "upload-area-id-" + count;

    const fileUploadGroup = `<div class="row clearfix file-upload-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_${count}" name="emp_doc_${count}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
            <select name="emp_doc_type_${count}" id="emp_doc_type_${count}" data-size="2" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose one of the following..." tabindex="-98"><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Choose one of the following...</option>
                <option value="OFFER LETTER">OFFER LETTER</option>
                <option value="APPOINTEMENT LETTER">APPOINTEMENT LETTER</option>
                <option value="CONFIRMATION LETTER">CONFIRMATION LETTER</option>
                <option value="APPRAISAL LETTER 1">APPRAISAL LETTER 1</option>
                <option value="APPRAISAL LETTER 2">APPRAISAL LETTER 2</option>
                <option value="RELIVING LETTER">RELIVING LETTER</option>
                <option value="EXPERIENCE / TERMINATION LETTER">EXPERIENCE / TERMINATION LETTER</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  waves-effect"><i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  waves-effect remove-me"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>
        
    </div>
</div>`;

    $(".upload-area").append(fileUploadGroup);

    // Increment the doc counter of hidden field
    $('#emp_docs_count').val(count);

    // Refresh the selectpicker to work on this generated element
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

Comment: send your html here

Comment: check in autoload.php $autoload['libraries'] =  array(''upload'); exists or not
$autoload['helper'] = array('file');

Comment: No need, I am sure it exist because I can upload an image file from one file input.

Comment: ok bro then fine

Comment: change `<input name="emp_doc_1" type="file" class="form-control">` to `<input name="emp_doc_1" type="file" class="form-control" multiple>` and then $_FILES return multiple image and you have to run foreach and do it for multiple files whatever you are doing for single image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864056/codeigniter-how-to-upload-original-image-with-thumbnail-image/32864540#32864540

Comment: This is not what i want. I have mentioned in my question that i have multiple file inputs and I want to upload multiple files through multiple file inputs tag not with the single file input tag

Comment: Okay then you need to change `name` attribute of input for all file type input  tags and then you will get different $_FILES array in your controller and now you will have to run it in foreach and upload all files one by one easily. Eg. `<input name="emp_doc_1" type="file" class="form-control">` `<input name="emp_doc_2" type="file" class="form-control">` etc

Comment: I am dynamically generating the input fields for that, Let me post that JS code

Comment: No problem you need to just increase your input name attribute by 1 every time when you create it dynamically and subtract the same 1 every time when remove it. But you have to make all input name field different from each other you can take help for jquery add/remove dynamic input from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701667/user-click-more-button-to-clone-and-if-user-click-add-less-button-to-remove-but/32865421#32865421

Comment: You can take name as name[] as well but at the time of saving details you won't be able to differentiate the file on the basis of name that which category it is falling

Comment: Yes that is the reason I need multiple file input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it, I just need to initialize upload library every time i call the `upload_file()` method, I have just added one line and it start working,

```
public function upload_file($dir, $input, $allowed_types = 'jpeg|jpg|png')
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = $dir;
        $config['allowed_types'] = !empty($allowed_types) ? $allowed_types : 'jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = 0;
        $config['max_width']     = 0;
        $config['max_height']    = 0;
        $config['file_name']     = md5(time() . rand(1, 1000));

        $this->load->library('upload');

        $this->upload->initialize($config); //<-- this line solved it

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($input)) {
            return array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            // If it is image then resize it to reduce the image file size
            if ($data['is_image']) {
                $this->resize_image($data['full_path']);
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your form input has attribute `enctype` is `multipart/form-data`
and your input as a file has name `name[]` (To create that each file in selected is on a array) and have the attribute `multiple`.

Comment: Read my question properly and I am using form_open_multipart got create form.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi and the name of the file should be like below.